# Encrypting and Decrypting Strings in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, .net-4.0, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encrypt/Decrypt string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-decrypt-string-in-net)

I've been searching all over Google for a simple way to do this, but they don't work in C# 4.0 which I'm using. I have a textbox where i input the string i want to encrypt, and then it encrypts that text and displays the encrypted version of the text on a label. Then, they put it in to the decrypt textbox, and push another button and it decrypts it. I'm going to put these functions in 2 different class libraries so I can re-use them without writing all of the code again. Does anyone have some source code, examples or tutorials that can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this has already been asked: [Encrypt and decrypt a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-decrypt-string-in-net)